# How to create specified form of POST data?

Tags: android, post

I have recently changed my Android app which used to send some `POST` data to server using `urlencode`. I just lost all of my code but I managed to save some logs of it. Here is one of the log:

```
activityId=gjWVbrn7r/zibT9BeQlqlA==
&senderDeviceId=MX460mXffhbuCIXZDl6jEC6TJKOipsTXRODilAaj+lVVEmDHvv0t6naJ2KPC+kDwJzkMqfGvcgJ6
qUJPYJzOZGeC0F0/XBtwEfLoWlhRonI=
&rewardQty=R9uVF1XvqTwG1arJeTXNfw==
&senderCity=he3AGPvAdLG5xsvv3gOp1A==
&senderGameId=1&senderMSISDN=a7HQTiNnMlcVzHplpbyWjA==
&senderGeo=ubWE7x5xNTRmqui34IVBjQ==
&senderBsbId=D+vv6zAuQwFRmGdSerPPVA7o5qLGgdcL9KetaTR8Svs=
&senderSimType=bRgYjQb/IQ2o2CR1srpFLA==
&senderNwVendor=hLrzjvqBQ93TDpSEYCrzIg==
```

I am trying to guess here that the data string `rewardQty=R9uVF1XvqTwG1arJeTXNfw==` (for example) is encoded somehow but I do not know yet how did I encoded it. You can tell me how to encode/encrypt (if required) a string to obtain the result as above?

It is like [dejavu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%25C3%25A9j%25C3%25A0_vu&ei=KsyYUoCSNcXXrQeZ74GQDw&usg=AFQjCNFigTdiiGZyihnFlS_jSGfPfiXufw&sig2=PwizPUruQJk0GR2uj9Kc3A) to me that I have somewhere in mind where it looks a similar string, just it is not clear how did I encoded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you used a hashing algorithm to encrypt the data sent from your app, such as MD5, SHA1, etc.  The giveaway is not only the alphabet used, but the '=' padding at the end for varying numbers of bits in the data.  If you don't recall what algorithm you used to encrypt the data, chances are that you didn't create your own custom function to hash the values, so you probably used a built in php hash function.

What I recommend is looking at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php

It is a list of all hash functions built in to php.  Look through here and see if any names ring a bell.  If not, try to remember what the value SHOULD be of one of these data fields, and try encrypting that value with a few algorithms from this list until the output matches your log.

Good luck.

Comment: thats it. I remembered now, that the data looks similar to what I usually store in my database for password. That is why I was having the `deja vu` feel because I knew I had seen this somewhere. Thanks for the click and instant answer though